# How to overlap multiple values in R pie chart?

Tags: r, ggplot2, charts

Here is my data frame:

```
frame1 <- data.frame(
  theLanguage = c ("English", "German", "Polish", "Russian", "Persian", 
"Bahasa Melayu", "Cantonese", "Hokkien", "Mandarin", "Telugu", "Spanish", 
"Arabic", "French"),
  theFreq = c(10,   1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  3,  1,  1)
  )
head(frame1,13)
dim(frame1)
```

The results are:

```
theLanguage theFreq
1         English      10
2         German       1
3         Polish       1
4        Russian       1
5        Persian       1
6  Bahasa Melayu       1
7      Cantonese       1
8        Hokkien       1
9       Mandarin       1
10        Telugu       1
11       Spanish       3
12        Arabic       1
13        French       1
```

Now I create a ggplot. NOTE: in my code, I already calling library(ggplot2)

```
 bp1<- ggplot(frame1, aes(x="", y=theFreq, fill=theLanguage))+
   geom_bar(width = 1, stat = "identity")
 bp1
```

[image: my bar graph]

This is when I create my pie graph & the resuls:

```
pie <- bp1 + coord_polar("y", start=0)
pie
```

[image: pie chart]

Here is the question. What can I do to present that the same people who speak English also speak Spanish? I have 10 people in my dataset but they may speak more than one language. I would like to present in a way it overlaps.

I was thinking that perhaps I have to add the count or peoples nick names. Any new ideas or suggestions? Right now my pie is misleading and confusing. I am not limited to pie charts; I can use anything else as well.

I appreciate your help!

Comment: This question is totally unrelated to Highcharts, so please remove that tag. Thank you!

Comment: Probably `frame1` is not a original dataset, as it shows only counts of people who speak given language... Data that shows that people can speak more than one language would be useful.

Comment: @FlorianAlbrecht , thank you for the comment of removing unrelated tags. For some reasons, the system did not let me put "pie charts" or "aggregation." The message I got was something like ** "you have to 1500 likes or reputation score to put those tags"**. I will keep your suggestion in mind.

Comment: @Adela good observation I was trying something else with "frame". I concur. In my original statement, I said: "I was thinking that perhaps I have to add the count or peoples nicknames."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is less to do with how to plot the data, and more about getting the dataframe in the right shape in the first place. Let's suppose you have a table which has the ID of each person and the languages they speak. As you have provided the aggregated dataset, I have made an example below:

```
languages <- 
  read.table(text = "
Person  Language
1   English
1   Arabic
1   German
2   English
2   Polish
2   French
3   English
3   Russian
4   English
4   Persian
5   English
5   'Bahasa Melayu'
5   Hokkien
6   English
6   Cantonese
6   Mandarin
7   English
7   Telugu
8   English
8   Spanish
9   English
9   Spanish
10  English
10  Spanish
", header = T, stringsAsFactors = F)
```

You need to aggregate this table so that you have a group for each combination of languages:

```
library(tidyverse)
# Aggregate the dataframe
df <- aggregate(Language ~ Person, data = languages, paste, collapse = " & ") %>%
  group_by(Language) %>%
  summarise(count = length(Language))
```

Which results in:

```
                           Language count
                              <chr> <int>
1         English & Arabic & German     1
2 English & Bahasa Melayu & Hokkien     1
3    English & Cantonese & Mandarin     1
4                 English & Persian     1
5         English & Polish & French     1
6                 English & Russian     1
7                 English & Spanish     3
8                  English & Telugu     1
```

Finally plotting this:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x="", y=count, fill=Language))+
  geom_bar(width = 1, stat = "identity") +
  coord_polar("y", start=0)
```

[image]

Comment: When I do df <- aggregate(Language ~Participant, data = myDemographic, paste, collapse = " & ") %>%
  group_by(Language)%>%
  summarise(count = length(Language)), in my Global environment, df is only 1 obs. of 1 variable.

I am suspecting that the function summarise() is causing the problem. When I don't add the summarise() I get the following information: (See next comment):    Participant                                                 Language
         <chr>                                                    <chr>
 1          P1 English & Bahasa Melayu & Cantonese & Hokkien & Mandarin

Comment: 2         P10                                        English & Persian
 3          P2                                         English & Telugu
 4          P3                                                  English
 5          P4                                English & Arabic & French
 6          P5                                        English & Spanish

Comment: 7          P6                                                  English
 8          P7                      English & German & Polish & Russian
 9          P8                                        English & Spanish
10          P9                                        English & Spanish

Comment: I didn't know what format you had your raw data in, so this was just one possible way of getting it suitable formatted.  Does the example work when you use my example code?

Comment: I keep getting 10 even when I do your df <- aggregate(...) I am not getting what you have for language and count. Am I missing something? When I do the ggplot i get Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (1): x, y, fill

Comment: Are you using the `languages` dataframe or your own data?

Comment: I have added the packages to the answer, in case you had something else loaded which was conflicting.

Comment: I copied your code above. I even installed the latest R and RStudio versions today November 27, 2017. Copied everything you have above to get a baseline.

Comment: I keep getting the 
Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (1): x, y, fill
when I copy the code above

Comment: So you are running this code line for line? https://gist.github.com/mikey-harper/1f301d40160cb41a58b9c19804a2d8fb . I have added a line to reinstall tidyverse in case you don't have the latest version

Comment: Okay This is what I found. For some reasons, The code shared by Mikey Harpter did not work in my Rstudio environment. However, when I run the code in R, it worked. I also had to install tidyverse by using install.packages("tidyverse"). I also had to intalled ggplot and ggplot2. When I run the code in R, I did get a warning Conflicts with dplyr::filter() masks stats::filter() and dplyr::lag()    masks stats::lag() when I calledlibrary(tidyverse) for the first time. After the warning I call library(tidyverse) again and it worked. Thank you! For now, I would say problem solved!

Comment: Great to hear you have resolved your problem. Would appreciate if you could upvote and mark the answer as accepted as a sign of appreciation for the time taken to help :)